# Automated integration testing in lambda support (golang, serverless)

Tags: go, lambda, automated-tests, integration-testing, aws-api-gateway

So I have a web app running in serverless. It spins up a bunch of lambdas and then a 'test' lambda is invoked at a later stage of our pipeline to run some api tests against the other lambbas. It passes or fails code pipeline depending on the result of the tests.

My concern is the implementation of the tests portion itself.

We're using golang, and I wasn't able to successfully find a way to have a bunch of go test files and run them, record the results and determine pass/fail or not.. but I wanted to use the test suite and library in order to run my assertions. So I came up with this solution which was to break about the go test library and run it myself using MainStart(), ex:

```
// T is used to manage our test cases manually using MainStart
type T struct{}

func (*T) ImportPath() string                          { return "" }
func (*T) MatchString(pat, str string) (bool, error)   { return true, nil }
func (*T) SetPanicOnExit0(bool)                        {}
func (*T) StartCPUProfile(io.Writer) error             { return nil }
func (*T) StopCPUProfile()                             {}
func (*T) StartTestLog(io.Writer)                      {}
func (*T) StopTestLog() error                          { return nil }
func (*T) WriteHeapProfile(io.Writer) error            { return nil }
func (*T) WriteProfileTo(string, io.Writer, int) error { return nil }

func (h *Handler) Handle(ctx context.Context, event events.CodePipelineEvent) (interface{}, error) {

    job := event.CodePipelineJob
    ok := runTest()
    
    if ok {
        logger.Info("Tests Passed!")
        input := &codepipeline.PutJobSuccessResultInput{
            JobId: &job.ID, 
        success, err := h.service.PutJobSuccessResult(input)
        return success, err
    } else {
        logger.Info("Tests Failed :(")
        input := &codepipeline.PutJobFailureResultInput{
            JobId: &job.ID,
            FailureDetails: &codepipeline.FailureDetails{
                Message: aws.String("tests failed"),
                Type:    aws.String("JobFailed"),
            },
            failure, err := h.service.PutJobFailureResult(input)
            return failure, err
        }
    }
}

// NewHandler returns a pointer to a Handler struct
func NewHandler(service *codepipeline.CodePipeline) *Handler {
    return &Handler{
        service,
    }
}

// runTest returns the test results
func runTest() bool {

    testSuite := []testing.InternalTest{
        {Name: "Test Service", F: TestService},
    }

    logger.Info("Running Tests")
    errors := testing.MainStart(&T{}, testSuite, nil, nil).Run()

    if errors == 0 {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

So the test looks like this:

```
func TestServices(t *testing.T) {
    logger.Info("blah blah do tests")
}
```

And for reference, main.go contains:

```
        // Initial code pipeline session
        cpSession := session.Must(session.NewSession())

        // Create the credentials from AssumeRoleProvider to assume the role
        // referenced by the "putJobResultRoleArn" ARN.
        creds := stscreds.NewCredentials(cpSession, "putJobResultRoleArn", func(p *stscreds.AssumeRoleProvider) {
            p.RoleARN = roleArn
            p.RoleSessionName = "put_job_result_session"
        })

        // Create a new instance of the CodePipeline client with a session
        svc := codepipeline.New(cpSession, &aws.Config{Credentials: creds})

        intTesthandler := inttest.NewHandler(
            svc,
        )

        lambda.Start(func(ctx context.Context, event events.CodePipelineEvent) (interface{}, error) {
            return intTesthandler.Handle(ctx, event)
        })
```

This works quite well, but what I don't like is:

- It's using an unsupported approach from golang that could break in the future
- I have to handhold any failures, meaning if one fails, I need to write code to stop the rest of the suite (if there were more tests) from running.
- Bit of a learning curve

To note the tests I have mainly do an http request to an api endpoint and validate the response + parse/store the data.

Anyone have any other creative solution? Is there a repo out there that makes it simple to run integration tests in golang?

Cheers